# Get array properties and values from other object

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i need to create a function that adds properties from the 2nd object to the 1st object. If the 1st object already has a given key, ignore it (it must not overwrite the property value). It must not modify the 2nd object at all.

Here's my code so far:

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  if(obj1.keys !== obj2.keys){
    obj1 = {
      obj2.keys;
    }
  }
}

var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> IT MUST RETURN {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> IT MUST RETURN {b: 4, c: 3}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you spend a fair amount of time trying things before you ask for help. I can tell this is a class assignment or other code challenge. You're not going to get as much out of it if you don't sit with it for an hour or so - a few different times. ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Loop through all properties of `obj2`
- For each property make sure that 1) the key does not already exist on `obj1` and 2) the key exists on the `obj2` itself and not somewhere on its prototype chain
- Add the property to `obj1` if test above is satisfied

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var prop in obj2) {
    if(!obj1.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
       obj1[prop] = obj2[prop];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## *"what am I doing wrong?"*

First of all: `obj1` and `obj2` won't in their expressed condition have a property `keys`, so attempting to compare them will be impossible; what you're actually doing with `if(obj1.keys !== obj2.keys)` is asking if `undefined !== undefined`.

Secondly: Objects and arrays (I assume this was what you hoped `obj*.keys` to be) comparison cannot be carried out in the same way we compare strings or numbers anyway.

You were perhaps misunderstanding how to use `Object.keys` to compare them. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for enlightenment.

Each key can be compared to another, but we cannot compare all of one set to all of another set in one hit. Typically, we would use some form of loop to work through them.

### `Object.assign()`

In JavaScript there are [many ways to loop through objects and arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), however, we can also [use `Object.assign()` to merge objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Merging_objects).

> The `Object.assign()`method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a `target` object. It will return the `target` object.
>
> **Syntax**
> `Object.assign(target, ...sources)`

In the example below, we **do not** merge `obj2` into `obj1` as the `target`, or `obj1` becomes `{a: 1, b: 4, c: 3}`. Instead we create a fresh object literal and supply it as the `target`, then assign it from the return value as the new value of `obj1`.
`obj2` remains unaffected.

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

obj1 = Object.assign( {}, obj2, obj1 );

console.log( obj1 ); // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log( obj2 ); // {b: 4, c: 3}
```

### `...`

*Soon (at time of posting) it will be* common to see objects being merged using [spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
var mergedObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
```

But the results may not be as desired in this question's particular case.